# SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from - XAMPP

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, xampp

I am getting an error:

> SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from
>   'https://apphom.correios.com.br/SigepMasterJPA/AtendeClienteService/AtendeCliente?wsdl'
>   : failed to load external entity
>   "https://apphom.correios.com.br/SigepMasterJPA/AtendeClienteService/AtendeCliente?wsdl

I'm using:

- XAMPP for Windows 5.6.15
  5.6.15
- Windows 8.1
- PHP Version 5.6.15

And in my php.ini I enabled the options:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
```

But I can not resolve the error, already researched several solutions.

The source code I'm trying to run is [here](https://github.com/stavarengo/php-sigep)

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem by rewriting my method

before

```
public static function getSoapClient()
{
    if (!self::$_soapClient) {
        $wsdl = Bootstrap::getConfig()->getWsdlAtendeCliente();

        self::$_soapClient = new \SoapClient($wsdl, array(
            "trace"              => Bootstrap::getConfig()->getEnv() != Config::ENV_PRODUCTION,
            "exceptions"         => Bootstrap::getConfig()->getEnv() != Config::ENV_PRODUCTION,
            'encoding'           => self::WEB_SERVICE_CHARSET,
            'connection_timeout' => 60,
            'cache_wsdl'         => WSDL_CACHE_MEMORY,
        ));
    }

    return self::$_soapClient;
}
```

after

```
public static function getSoapClient()
{
    if (!self::$_soapClient) {
        $wsdl = Bootstrap::getConfig()->getWsdlAtendeCliente();

        $opts = array(
            'ssl' => array(
                'ciphers'           =>'RC4-SHA', 
                'verify_peer'       =>false, 
                'verify_peer_name'  =>false
            )
        );
        // SOAP 1.1 client
        $params = array (
            'encoding'              => self::WEB_SERVICE_CHARSET, 
            'verifypeer'            => false, 
            'verifyhost'            => false, 
            'soap_version'          => SOAP_1_1, 
            'trace'                 => Bootstrap::getConfig()->getEnv() != Config::ENV_PRODUCTION,
            'exceptions'            => Bootstrap::getConfig()->getEnv() != Config::ENV_PRODUCTION, 
            "connection_timeout"    => 180, 
            'stream_context'        => stream_context_create($opts) 
        );

        self::$_soapClient = new \SoapClient($wsdl, $params);
    }

    return self::$_soapClient;
}
```